# perl Template: add a variable alongside a list

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have perl generating a list through Template Toolkit.

How do I add a couple of single non-list variables into the mix, e.g. to include outside of the `FOREACH` within the `.tt2` file?

---

```
my $e = {
};
for my $c (sort keys %$cat) {
        push @{$e->{categories}},
            {
                name => $c,
                url => "$c"
            };
}
$template->process('main.tt2', $e, "index.html") or die;
```

---

```
<ul>
[% FOREACH c IN categories -%]
<li><a href="[% c.url | url %]">[% c.name %]</a></li>
[% END %]
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$e->{somethingElse} = "some value";
```

and

```
[% somethingElse | html %]
```

Comment: Thanks!  May I ask what does this notation, `->{}`, actually mean?

Comment: The arrow accesses a reference (on the left hand side), the `{}` contains the name of the key in a hash reference.